# What is Full stack mvc framework? How Grails is full stack framework?

Tags: grails, model-view-controller

I am new to Grails and in the Grails website I found the following sentence.

> Grails is an Open Source, full stack, web application framework for the JVM.

What is full stack web application framework? How Grails vary from Struts?
Thanks

Comment: Did you search and did not find any thing about those terms used in question?

Comment: Yes, I did searched and did not found anything that explains why Grails is "full stack" and how it differs from Struts

Comment: It's one of those gray terms. My interpretation is a full stack framework has builtin support from the data store up to the user. Grails vs Struts is a different question. No clue, but Google came up with lots of comparisons. Here's a cool link http://codingarchitect.wordpress.com/2012/10/22/full-stack-frameworks-vs-non-full-stack-frameworks/ (yeah its for JS but I mean the terminology).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally when you build applications you need some functionalities:

- Database managment (ORM)
- Presentation (User Interface)
- Service Layer
- Configuration

You can build your application using one API/Framework for each area.

The full stack means that Grails will provide you functionality to all those areas so you don't need to look for a set of frameworks, just use one.