# What is the definition of a Full-Stack Web Application Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, laravel, frameworks, mean-stack

I see this term Full-Stack Framework, when dealing with Web Application Framework, but there seems to be different opinions on it, and would therefore like to hear your opinions.

I've read this thread on stackoverflow ([What is Full stack mvc framework? How Grails is full stack framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19050205/what-is-full-stack-mvc-framework-how-grails-is-full-stack-framework)) but, it doesn't clarify the UI part enough?

In the Laravelbook (http://laravelbook.com/laravel-architecture/) it says:
"Laravel is referred to as a “full stack” framework because it handles everything from web serving to database management right down to HTML generation."

So by this definition ASP.NET MVC would also be a Full-Stack Framework?

But just because you can serve an end user with HTML, does it then make it a Full-Stack? What about the interaction (JavaScript)? Like this article says, http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/11/21/introduction-to-full-stack-javascript/

MEAN is also referred to as Full-Stack Framework and has AngularJS included for the user-interaction? I've read that this makes MEAN truly a Full-Stack Framework, and if Laravel or ASP.NET MVC is combined with lets say AngularJS, then these would be a Full-Stack Web Application Framework.

And this is where i get confused, because with Laravel or ASP.NET MVC you can build an application alone with the framework it self, and also ASP.NET have async operations build-in with controllers, so maybe would't need something like Angular?

Isn't the JS interactions like the ones you can do with Angular just a matter of opinion, and what about just using plain old jQuery library for the DOM updates? Does the Full-Stack need to have a JS framework?

How do you define or argument for something being a Full-Stack Web Application Framework?

Answer (score 1):

A full-stack framework is able to handle everything you need to build a complete web application. It is not saying that you can't add anything else to it that might make it easier for you to achieve certain goals such as using Laravel for the back-end and AngularJS for the front-end.

Framework combining rises out of wanting to find the best possible solution for what you are trying to achieve. In the example mentioned above, developers find it beneficial to let AngularJS handle the front-end not only because it might make it easier to create a dynamic single page application, but also to achieve code separation between the front-end and back-end. This allows your application to be more modular, which we all know has a lot of benefits (testing, api creation, third party integration, etc).

In the end, it all depends on what you are trying to achieve. If your goal is to have a simple web application you might only need to have one full-stack framework, but if your application has multiple ambitions then you might find that combining frameworks would be the best possible solution.